# How to get expected behavior from the select values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZ7c7.gif) is the solution i want which i want to implement the below code like [Kendo combobox](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/combobox/index).

I mean when user types mercury and clicks the mouse in side without selection it should be selected.

```js
$(function(){
    $(".chosen-select").chosen();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/chosen.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/chosen.jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    
<div>
          <em>Multiple Select with Groups</em><br>
          <select data-placeholder="select planets" style="width:350px;" class="chosen-select" multiple tabindex="6">
            <option value=""></option>
            <optgroup label="Planets">
              <option>Mercury</option>
              <option>Venus</option>
              <option>Earth</option>
              <option>Mars</option>
            </optgroup>
            
          </select>
        </div>
```